# How to add columns that have same name

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have large datasets, that is two data frame. and want to add value that has the same column name in the other one data frame. how do I set the code?

```
df1
a b c
0 0 0
0 0 0

df2
a c d
1 1 0
0 1 0
```

what I expected is:

```
a b c
1 0 1
0 0 1
```

it means I'm in charge to stay with colnames df1 but the value is in df2. thanks for the help. have a good day

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add"?

Comment: sorry yes my grammar is not good, sorry :D. I mean how to add `value` when it has the same column names. but it has to be arranged like `df1` the `colnames` has to be `order` like `df1` but the `value` is like the `df2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Works with `data.frame`

```
    data.frame(lapply(X = split.default(x = cbind(df1, df2),
                                        f = c(names(df1), names(df2))),
                      FUN =  rowSums))[names(df1)]
    #  a b c
    #1 1 0 1
    #2 0 0 1
```

2. Works with `data.frame` and `matrix`

```
    nm = intersect(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))
    nm1 = colnames(df1)[!colnames(df1) %in% nm]

    m = cbind(df1[, nm1, drop = FALSE], df1[, nm, drop = FALSE] + df2[, nm, drop = FALSE])
    colnames(m) = c(nm1, nm)
    m[,colnames(df1)]
    #  a b c
    #1 1 0 1
    #2 0 0 1
```

---

```
#DATA
df1 = structure(list(a = c(0L, 0L), b = c(0L, 0L), c = c(0L, 0L)),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 = structure(list(a = 1:0, c = c(1L, 1L), d = c(0L, 0L)),
                class = "data.frame",
                row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: A different spin on the second option - `replace(df1, nm, df1[nm] + df2[nm])`

Comment: thanks but i had to correct it first `nm = intersect(colnames(df1),colnames(df2))`

Comment: @thelatemail is not working with replace because it turns out to NA value, it is for vector, what is the function if it matrix?

Comment: @d.b yes i got it in `csv` files so could you fix it? i would glad

Comment: @d.b yes it's work thanks btw, but I have to arranged the colnames like df1